# How would video be posted to the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Are people going to post the videos on their own youtube accounts and then use those in their blog post?  If so, are the moderators going to download and re-up them to a DIY.SE YT account?

If not, how are they going to be submitted, and what web site is going to distribute them?  SE could host the videos themselves, but are they willing to deal with the bandwidth issues?

Anyways, it shouldn't be all that hard to take care of, but it seems like something that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Without anyone else having weighed in on this -- Aarthi, I think we need to kick this question up the chain a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and easiest option would be for people to simply post them on YouTube, would it not?  Is there a reason it needs to be more complicated than this?

Comment: Persistence. Basically for the same reason that the stack exchange sites mostly want you to upload photos rather than just linking to them.

Comment: Is persistence an issue with YT videos?  (I really don't use YT other than clicking on "hilarious" videos people insist I watch.)  We want photos uploaded to our imgur account so that they don't disappear due to age.  I wasn't aware this is an issue with YT.

Comment: It can be for the same reason that uploading to flickr is not persistent -- people's accounts go stale or are locked due to various reasons. The only way to keep anything persistent is to put it in a place where you can hold on to it.

Comment: I think there are existing places perfectly capable of sticking around and handling the space/bandwidth that it isn't something we need to spend time and resources on.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't a blanket policy. Running streaming servers is a pain in the butt. (Ask me how I know...)